# need to copy all rows with C_PROV_TYPE ='014' and C_SPECILTY = '300' and insert back 3 rows with same data + max sequence number + 1 i.e =4,5,6

Tags: db2

[image: need to copy and insert back all rows with C_PROV_TYPE ='014' and C_SPECILTY = '300']

> need 3 rows for each one of the two valid rows displayed below output like below:
>
> Primary key is C_PROCEDURE + C_PROV_TYPE + SPEC_SEQ_NO!
> output shall be like bELOW[image]

Comment: Do new C_SPECIALTY values depend on the C_SPECIALTY value of the source rows? I.e. if it was 400, would the new rows need to be accordingly assigned C_SPECIALTY of 401, 402, 403? Also, is C_SPECIALTY really a numeric column?

Comment: yes, only rows who have C_SPecialty = 300 should be taken ..and for output max seq number should be 
MAx (Seq number) +1 of C_procedure who have C_SPecialty = 300

Comment: Example:
in the input picture above .. if ve have one more row having C_PROCEDURE =S9480 and Specilty = 000 but sequence number =7  then we have not to fetch that row but the sequence number of out rows for C_PROCEDURE S9480 should start from 8

Comment: get maxsequence number for  of C_procedure with any specilty
now select only those rows who have specilty = 300
 , then make three new rows for that row having that fetched max seq number +1 and sepcilty =301
 , , and maxseq number +2 and specilty =302 and so will be 3rd line to be inserted

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (
  C_PROCEDURE,
  C_PROV_TYPE,
  I_PT_SPEC_SEQ_NO,
  C_SPECIALTY
)
SELECT
  s.C_PROCEDURE,
  s.C_PROV_TYPE,
  s.MaxSeq + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY s.C_PROCEDURE, s.C_PROV_TYPE
    ORDER BY v.rn, s.I_PT_SPEC_SEQ_NO),
  s.C_SPECIALTY + v.rn
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(I_PT_SPEC_SEQ_NO) OVER (
      PARTITION BY C_PROCEDURE, C_PROV_TYPE
    ) AS MaxSeq
  FROM YourTable
) s
CROSS JOIN (
  VALUES (1), (2), (3)
) v (rn)
WHERE s.C_PROV_TYPE = '014'
  AND s.C_SPECIALTY = '300'
;
```

Basically, the subquery returns all the `YourTable` rows supplied with the maximum values of `I_PT_SPEC_SEQ_NO` for every partition of `(C_PROCEDURE, C_PROV_TYPE)` using the windowing `MAX()` function (`MAX(...) OVER (...)`).

The resulting set of that subquery is then cross-joined to an inline 3-row table (which produces three copies of every row returned) and filtered by the specified values of `C_PROV_TYPE` and `C_SPECIALTY`.

New data rows pull `C_PROCEDURE` and `C_PROV_TYPE` directly from the subquery. The new `C_SPECIALTY` values are produced using those from the subquery and the `rn` values of the inline table. The new sequence numbers are generated with the help of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and the maximum sequence numbers returned by the subquery.

As I didn't have access to a working installation of DB2, I was testing my script in SQL Server 2008, trying to stick to features that I understood DB2 supported as well as SQL Server. [This SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54681/1) also uses a SQL Server 2008 instance to demonstrate how the query works.